# How to split a string having values "." seperated in SQL

Tags: sql

For Eg; abc.def.efg , separate into independent strings as abc def efg

| Head |
| --- |
| abc.def.efg |

to

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | efg |

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server - I removed the conflicting tags, please add the TAG for the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: You have tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]. These are two different products, and the solution to your question may be different depending on which one you use. Can you please clarify which one you really use?

Comment: Once we get which RDBMS you are using (which I agree is super important to this question as the logic will definitely vary by product)... is the pattern always <string>.<string>.<string> being separated out into 3 columns or would the pattern vary like `<string>.<string>` or `<string>.<string>.<string>.<string>` and if it does vary, what would the output look like?

Comment: What have you tried?  Surely you've tried researching this task and found a ton of answers.  Please edit your question and add in your sql query and explain how it's not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `split_part()` equivalent for the RDBMS you're using.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
    split_part(Head, '.', 1) AS "left",
    split_part(Head, '.', 2) AS center,
    split_part(Head, '.', 3) AS "right"
FROM your_table
```

EDIT: corrected the indexes, see: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/

Comment: `split_part` seems to be for PostgreSQL, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=060432b80dbf4ac365d8e268dc9708a8) which also has the correct indexes...

Comment: Good catch, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server with a 3-part delimited string you can use *parsename*

```
with t as (
  select 'left.centre.right' Head
)
select ParseName(Head,3) L, ParseName(Head,2) C, ParseName(Head,1) R
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

on MySQL, you can do:

```
with t as (
   select 'left.centre.right' Head
 )
 select 
   substring_index(Head,'.',1) as L,
   substring_index(substring_index(Head,'.',2),'.',-1) as M,
   substring_index(Head,'.',-1) as R
 from t;
```

results:

| L | M | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| left | centre | right |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98a54454b916f3425d7ebe502ff525d0), and [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)